# Remove page timeout for single path?

Tags: php, apache

We've got a report that needs to be generated at /our/really-cool/report, but the dataset being queried is causing a timeout. Is it possible to leave the regular timeout for the sever, but somehow set it to infinite for just this path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) with a value of `0`. As stated in the parameter docs:

> The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

You may also want to look at [`max_execution_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) which should be able to set in your script with `ini_set()` assuming your are not in safe mode.

Comment: Would this not just affect the entire server?

Comment: No, just set this in the script that runs for path `/our/really-cool/report`

Comment: Since it's being run by an operation in a Drupal site I guess I'll need to find a Drupal-specific way to handle my use case. Thanks, though!

Comment: If you are using Drupal then I would assume there's some way to hook into a specific route. Could be an option?

Comment: Yeah I'd wager that's the way to do it, just not exactly sure how. I've posted another question over at https://drupal.stackexchange.com -- I'm sure I'll have some more luck over there